# Do we compute the integral in that way?

Tags: calculus, integration

I want to compute the integral $\iint_D \frac{y-x}{x+y}dxdy$ where $D:y=x+1, y=x, y=-x+2, y=-x+1$.

I made the graph of the region $D$, it is a rhombus.

So, we have to divide the region into the regions: $D_1=\{0\leq x\leq \frac{1}{2}, \ -x+1\leq y\leq x+1\}$ and $D_2=\{\frac{1}{2}\leq x\leq 1, \ x\leq y\leq -x+2\}$, or not?

I have done the following: 
\begin{align*} \iint_D \frac{y-x}{x+y}dxdy&=\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}}\int_{-x+1}^{x+1} \frac{y-x}{x+y}dydx+\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^1\int_{x}^{-x+2} \frac{y-x}{x+y}dydx \\ & = \int_0^{\frac{1}{2}}\int_{-x+1}^{x+1} \left [\frac{y}{x+y}-\frac{x}{x+y}\right ]dydx+\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^1\int_{x}^{-x+2} \left [\frac{y}{x+y}-\frac{x}{x+y}\right ]dydx \\ & = \int_0^{\frac{1}{2}}\int_{-x+1}^{x+1} \left [\frac{y+x-x}{x+y}-\frac{x}{x+y}\right ]dydx+\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^1\int_{x}^{-x+2} \left [\frac{y+x-x}{x+y}-\frac{x}{x+y}\right ]dydx \\ & = \int_0^{\frac{1}{2}}\int_{-x+1}^{x+1} \left [1-\frac{2x}{x+y}\right ]dydx+\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^1\int_{x}^{-x+2} \left [1-\frac{2x}{x+y}\right ]dydx \\ & = \int_0^{\frac{1}{2}}\left [2x-2x\ln (2x+1)\right ]dx+\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^1\left [-2x+2-2x\ln 2+2x\ln (2x)\right ]dx \\ & =\frac{1}{8}-\frac{1}{8}\left (\log (4)-1\right ) \\ & = \frac{1}{8}-\frac{1}{8}\log (4)-\frac{1}{8} \\ & = -\frac{1}{8}\log (4) \end{align*}

Is everything correct?

Comment: You could try a change of variables too: $u=y-x$, $v=y+x$.

Comment: What you did is fine, but the shape of the equations strongly hints you to perform a change of variable with $x+y$ and $x-y$. Didn't you just learn about Jacobians ?

Comment: Ah ok... But in the way I did we also get the correct result, or not? Are the bounds I wrote correct? @HansLundmark

Comment: Ah ok... But in the way I did we also get the correct result, or not? Are the bounds I wrote correct? @YvesDaoust

Comment: "did we also get the correct result": how can I know, you didn't give it !

Comment: I posted what I have done in my post above. Could you take a look at it? @YvesDaoust

Comment: @MaryStar: I didn't look in detail, but the shape of the expression is correct.  And by the other method (mentally), the answer must be a simple rational multiple of $\log2$.

Comment: Ah I see!! Thank you very much!! :-) @YvesDaoust